# How to float a div inside unfloated div?

Tags: css, html, styles

I have a simple problem with divs. How can I float 3 DIVs inside one DIV that's not floated?

Here is my code:

```
<div style="margin:0 auto;width:1240px;border:1px solid #000000;">
    <div style="width:200px;height:50px;float:left;border:1px solid #000000;">
        test    
    </div>
    <div style="width:200px;height:50px;float:left;border:1px solid #000000;">
        test    
    </div>
    <div style="width:200px;height:50px;float:left;border:1px solid #000000;">
        test    
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to float child DIVs inside this parent DIV or a way to center them without floating...display:inline-block won't work for the child divs as they are of different heights and one div is an image...so i think the best way is to float them and optimize the margins...In this case i want the parent div to be centered across the screen so i use margin:0 auto instead of float but this leads to the child div not stretching the parent div and it appears as a thin line.

You can test the fiddle I created to understand the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/tQpM5/

Thanks

Comment: Could you complete your fiddle with all the divs and images you're working with, so we can figure out what you mean easier?

Comment: You need to clear the floats. There are numerous techniques to do that.

Comment: I'd think `display: inline-block` would work just fine if you also `vertical-align: top`.  But eh.

Comment: the code refrences images and styles on my server so can't post them there...i just want the concept to achieve this not exact measure...thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to center 3 boxes on the same row:

```
.wrapper{
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.box{
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box"> 1 </div>
  <div class="box"> 2 </div>
  <div class="box"> 3 </div>
</div>
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pNLtd/)

Comment: `vertical-align: top;` did the trick :) the problem was with vertical aligning as one div appeared higher than the 2 others and all were on the same line inside the parent div...so the problem was with aligning them vertically...thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to give the parent div: `overflow:hidden;` so it can contain its child div.

Child divs will float beside each other, however when you re-size your browser, they will float under each other, to avoid this, you can give the parent div a `min-width`.

To center the parent div, you can give it a `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;`, however you must specify a width so that it does not stretch and take all its available width.

Since you chose to use floats and not `inline-block`, then the only thing left is to deal with `margins` just like you said.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nQXJr/)

Answer (score 1):

Since all the child divs widths are less than that of the parents, they should naturally line up side by side. Try give each child div a position: relative;  margin: auto. This way they should center themselves with in the parent

Answer (score 1):

The parent div appears as a line because its contents is floating, settings its height to 1px. To resolve this you need to  clear the floats after this element. Often referred to as clearfix.

```
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
```

Then you can just float the children as normal. I used margin: auto on the parent to make it centered.

See this demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/c2NjZ/

Note for old browser support on clearfixing see:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Comment: Note, "old browser" basically means "IE7".  :)

Answer (score 1):

The container div's float and it's child div's float values (or no float) are independent of each other, you just need to clear the child div's before you close the parent div:

```
<style type="text/css">
.clearfloat {clear:both;height:0;font-size:1px;line-height:0px;}
</style>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child" style="float:left;">
        Hi
    </div>
    <div class="child" style="float:right;">
        There
    </div>
    <br class="clearfloat">
</div>
```

Update to your example: http://jsfiddle.net/tQpM5/2/